# I am using org.htmlparser.Parser to parse URL but its failing for external URLS and giving Connection Refused: connect error

Tags: java, html-parsing, html-parser

I am using org.htmlparser.Parser to parse URL, it works fine for all internal URLs that are in network. But when i try opening external URLs, it gives

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.htmlparser.util.ParserException:
>   Connection refused: connect;
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: connect

This line is failing -

> Parser p = new
>   Parser("http://www.google.com");

I can open external URLs in browser using proxy. So i am doing the proxy authentication using Authenticator class in the code as well but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the proxy connectivity parameters when you run the java program

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL
     -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber
     -Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName
     -Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword javaClassToRun
```

Comment: Added this in the code...but its not working...  System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", <proxyURL>);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", <proxyPort>);
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", <proxyUserName>);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", <proxyPassword>);